# How do I access a video src listed as a property from an imported Array which uses map() to display the videos in a Carousel in React JS?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, events, video, methods

This is a simple problem but the solution seems way more complex when using ReactJS.

How would I be able to reference a "video" property for **media events** and **media methods** from an imported array file in which I used the "map()"array method to display videos in a carousel using ReactJS?

The reason why I want access to the videos properties is because I want to prevent the user from having multiple videos play at the same time if they decide to switch slides and play another video in my carousel.

Below I've listed my code. 
First you will see the array which is named **VideoClips.jsx** that imported and then you will see the code where I tried to apply my current issue.

Many thanks if you have any solutions!

```
//Video Slide Data

import SundayVid from '../assets/Sunday-Skate-Movie.mp4';
import BuffaloDemo from '../assets/Channel-4-Sabres-PKG.mp4';
import BuffSpyVid from '../assets/SPOR_original.mp4'



export default [
    {
        title: "Sunday Skate Video",
        video: SundayVid,
    },
    {
        title: "Buffalo Demo Package",
        video: BuffaloDemo,
    },
    {
        title: "Sweet Plans of Revenge",
        video: BuffSpyVid,
    },
]
```

```
import React from 'react';
import VideoClips from '../side-components/VideoClips.jsx';
import '../stylesCSS/carouselStyle.css';

class VideoCarousel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activeIndex: 0,
            length: VideoClips.length,
            landing: VideoClips,
        }

        this.mediaControl = this.mediaControl.bind(this)
    }

    goToPrevSlide = () => {
        let index = this.state.activeIndex;
        let length = this.state.length

        if (index < 1) {
            index = length - 1
        } else {
            index--
        }

        this.setState({
            activeIndex: index,
            mediaPlaying: false,
        })
    }

    goToNextSlide = () => {
        let index = this.state.activeIndex;
        let length = this.state.length;

        if (index === length - 1) {
            index = 0
        } else {
            index++
        }

        this.setState({
            activeIndex: index,
        })
    }

    /* The browser gives me an error on this method when I try to reference the videos */
    /*This is just a test to see if it worked, but you will see it does not if you decide to run it*/

    mediaControl = () => {
      if(this.state.landing[0]) {
            this.state.landing[1].pause()
      }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>

                <div className='slider'>
                    <div className='slider-items'>

                        <div className="backArrow" onClick={this.goToPrevSlide}>
                            Prev
                        </div>

                        <section>
                            {
                                this.state.landing.map((s, index) =>
                                    <div className={
                                        index === this.state.activeIndex ? 'active' : 'inactive'}
                                        key={index}>
                                        <h2>{s.title}</h2>
                                        <video src={s.video}
                                            onPlaying={this.mediaControl}
                                            controls />
                                    </div>
                                    )}
                        </section>

                        <div className="nextArrow" onClick={this.goToNextSlide}>
                            Next
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default VideoCarousel
```

The browser gives me an error.

```
 if (this.state.VideoClips[0].video) {
   this.state.VideoClips[1].pause()
}
```

Or even when I try to put the video data in the state.

```
this.state = {
video1: VideoClips[0].video
video2: VideoClips[1].video
}

//Then Referencing as...

if(this.state.video1) {
this.state.video2.pause()
}
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks again

Comment: what is the error? also have you logged ```VideoClips``` what does it look like?

Comment: Thank you for looking at my code @HadiPawar.
The error says ```TypeError: this.state.landing[1].pause is not a function```.
I have logged ```VideoClips``` to the console and it gives me all the properties in my Array. If I logged ```VideoClips[0].video``` to the console, it would give me the exact source of the video.